# Post Doc in Norway research atmosphere

Tags: postdocs

I was recommended for a post doc in Norway. I was wondering how is the research typical atmosphere in Norway. Here in the UK you spend more time writing proposals or trying to do research that can be published quickly and get funding rather than anything that contributes in my experience. Should I expect the same in Norway? It's fine if the answer is yes, the subject in question is interesting enough and the pay seems decent and I need a job.
Thanks

Comment: Why not ask the person offering the job what your duties will be?  This is far more likely to be important than a general UK/Norway difference. (And your description of UK research is far from universal).

Comment: "you spend more time writing proposals or trying to do research that can be published quickly". This is essentially what a postdoc should do. Learn how to attract funding and publish. What else do you want to do?

Comment: As for the job description, its very general and the person I will be working for got some money they want to spend with no specific research goal.

Comment: What I want to do is contribute to science, something that may not make money in the next 10 or 20 years but has real application as technology progresses rather than something the government or companies are interested in today and can get votes or money. I have lots of ideas in the field, what I'm asking is if I will alienate people by suggesting such things as it is the case in the UK, hence the question about research culture.

Comment: @SaeidAlami  You want to work on something where funding is not available?  That will be very difficult anywhere, but "How can I work on my research interest where funding is not available?" would make a very good question for this site.  I don't think you have framed it correctly here.  Also, I think your view of research funding is somewhat cynical.  Lots of work that has long-term potential gets funded.

Comment: *Here in the UK you spend more time writing proposals*, that's not always the case.  I work on a EU H2020 project that has been funded for 4 years, and I spend my time essentially doing research.

Comment: What discipline/area are we talking about here? I think the academic cultures and problems vary considerably between different subjects

Comment: @gerrit That's because you (or someone else) spent a *lot* of time writing that proposal in the past.

Answer (score 3):

From my limited experience of having worked both in Norway and the UK, I get the impression that there is less pressure in Norway than in the UK. Given the vast difference in population, it is however only natural to expect more competition in the UK than that in Norway. Also Norwegian policies seem to be more welcoming to third-country nationals.

I would however disagree that spending more time writing proposals or trying to do research that can be published quickly and get funding are necessarily opposed to anything that contributes to experience. In fact, your productivity tends to increase when you have less external pressure to dictate what you need to do.

So a place where one can thrive is not necessarily country-specific, although for some, it may be.